# Javafx CheckBoxTableCell generic

Tags: generics, javafx-8

I am new to JavaFX and have some problem creation a TableView wrapper. Creating a Tableview shall be as simple as just providing Data and some backroundinformation therefor i made some Annotations on class.fields and methods of my Model.

```
@AsTableColumn(text = "Birthday", index = 2)
private Date birtyday;

@AsTableColumn(text = "Day of death", index = 3)
private Date deathDay;

@AsTableColumn(text = "Alive?", index = 4)
public boolean isAlive() {
    return this.getDeathDay().compareTo(new Date()) > 0;
}
```

The Columns are made in the following function:

```
    private static <S, T> TableColumn<S, T> createTableColumn(Class<T> type, String fieldName, String columnHeader, String index) {
    TableColumn<S, T> col = new TableColumn<S, T>(columnHeader);
    col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
        try {
            Object o = getAttribute(fieldName, cellData.getValue());
            // Erzeuge eine Property, die das Attribut enthält
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            SimpleObjectProperty<T> property = new SimpleObjectProperty<T>((T) o);
            return property;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    });
    if (type.equals(Boolean.TYPE))
        col.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<S, T>, TableCell<S, T>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<S, T> call(TableColumn<S, T> p) {
                return new CheckBoxTableCell<S, T>();
            }
        });
    col.setId(index);
    return col;
}
```

Which works great, despite of one fact: reading "true" and "false" in a Table is annoying. I would like to use CheckBoxTableCell but the way i am doing it wont work. All the checkboxes are empty. I know i need to specify the source of the boolean Values by .forTableColumn() but everything i try is having problems with Generics. Like `TableColumn<S,T>` is not a`TableColumn<S,Boolean>`.

It would be great to have some help.

Comment: I think you can safely do a cast in the `if (type.equals(Boolean.TYPE))` clause: `TableColumn<S,Boolean> boolCol = (TableColumn<S,Boolean>) col;`. (The compiler will warn you, but you know this is safe because of the `if` statement.) Then you are good, no?

Comment: @James_D i am one step further. Its compiling and it looks good now. thanks for that but the data is wrong. The Whole Column is unchecked which is wrong i know for sure because i created the testdata inside the code.
`  if (type.equals(Boolean.TYPE)) {
   TableColumn<S, Boolean> bcol = (TableColumn<S, Boolean>) col;
   bcol.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(bcol));
   col = (TableColumn<S, T>) bcol;
  }` what have i forgotten